# Loop from x1,y1 to x2,y2, no matter in which order they are

Tags: c#

I want to be able to select part of an image via two Points (p1,p2). My problem is that I want to use the same loop regardless in which order they are.

right now I have this:

```
for (int x = p1.X; x != p2.X; x += Math.Sign(p2.X - p1.X))
        {
            for (int y = p1.Y; y != p2.Y; y += Math.Sign(p2.Y - p1.Y))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} {1}", x, y));
            }
        }
```

With that loop I don't get all of the numbers:
e.g. from 1/1 to 3/3 only gones till 2/2.

I some how need to loop through both loops one more time, but since I don't know which way I'm actually looping (decreasing or increasing) I can't just add/ subtract one from the loop.

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Point p1 = new Point(1, 1);
Point p2 = new Point(3, 3);

int dx = Math.Sign(p2.X - p1.X);
int dy = Math.Sign(p2.Y - p1.Y);

for (int x = p1.X; x != p2.X + dx; x += dx)
{
    for (int y = p1.Y; y != p2.Y + dy; y += dy)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: The key is comparing x to p2.X + dx rather than just p2.X.

Comment: After stepping through it twice, I get it

Answer (score 5):

You can just loop from the lowest X to the highest X, and then do the same for Y.

```
for (int x = Math.Min(p1.X, p2.X); x <= Math.Max(p1.X, p2.X); x++){
  for (int y = Math.Min(p1.Y, p2.Y); y <= Math.Max(p1.Y, p2.Y); y++){
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} {1}", x, y));
  }
}
```

This will not walk down from [3,3] to [1,1].  If you actually care about the direction, this approach won't work.

Comment: Well the input can come in either way, but it wasn't clear whether he just needed to cover all the pixels between those points OR whether it should be done in the order corresponding to the input.

Comment: The actual directions isn't important, so this would works. Thank you!